# Read subprocess output without redirecting

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script that is launching a `subprocess` executable, which I'd like to create in its own window and have it print its output into that window. At the same time, I'd like to read the output of that process in the main script. I've tried using `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, but this redirects the output such that nothing is written to the new window. Any ideas on how to have the subprocess's output be readable by the main script and written in the new window?

Comment: Could you share some code that could be used for testing?

Comment: Write the text to the window as it comes in on the pipe.

Comment: I understand he wants output in subprocess window instead of the main program, which means it is too late if it is only captured from the pipe in the main program. There appears to be some attempts to write `tee` in Python, not sure how successful they are. Here is one http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-tee.html